# In blender 2.83 after frame 500 blender crash throwing an instance of 'Manta::Error'

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation

I am using blender smoke simulation and it is rendering well but after frame 500 blender crash and in terminal i can see

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'Manta::Error'
  what():  can't clean grid cache, some grids are still in use
Error raised in /home/sources/buildbot-x86_64-slave/linux_glibc217_x86_64_cmake/blender.git/extern/mantaflow/preprocessed/fluidsolver.cpp:33
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I am using ubuntu 20.04 
And same error has occurred 3 time.

Comment: Try rendering in blocks. Eg frame 1 to 400, 401 to 800.

Comment: Yeaaa @batFINGER also downloading 2.85

Comment: @batFINGER After that it crashes on someother frame